# select value into variable and alias in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax, alias

I'd like to simultaneously do two things in an MSSQL query:

1. select a field's value into a variable
   `select @myvar = colName from tableName`
2. alias my column 
   `select colName as [myCol] from tableName`

I've tried these things:

- Attempted Syntax `select @myvar = colName as [myCol] from tableName`
- Attempted Syntax `select @myvar = (colName as [myCol]) from tableName`
- Attempted Syntax `select (@myvar = colName) as [myCol] from tableName`
- checked select statement syntax: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx

If this is possible, how can it be accomplished?

Comment: Why you need alias when assigning value to variable?

Comment: What impact would the alias have after the select? It would not be associated with @myvar and a select-assign returns no rows, do you want to assign and select as a row? - if so just `select @myvar as [myCol]`

Comment: @Faisal I don't strictly need the alias, but I desire it for maintenance reasons.

Comment: @AlexK. Impact: None on execution of the query. I don't want to select the variable value as a row, no. Thanks!

Comment: `select @myvar = (select (select colName as [myCol] from tableName))` is probably the closes you will get if you want to do come kinf of textual analysis on the source

Comment: You can either assign values to variables or return columns, but not both in a single `select`. An [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause is worth learning about, but it may not help in this case.

Comment: *"I don't strictly need the alias, but I desire it for maintenance reasons"* what reasons are they? if it's readability you can simply add a comment, that will no doubt help readability better then a column alias.

Comment: @ZoharPeled When someone debugs the code later, I want them to know what they're looking at. A comment is a very good alternative. Thanks!

Comment: @HABO Thanks for answering my question! Feel free to make your comment an answer so I can flag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `select` can either [assign](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx) values to variables or [return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) column values, but not both.

In some cases, e.g. when using `select` to provide data to an `insert`, an [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause may be useful.  A tool well worth having in your pocket as it provides access to identity values from `insert` and both *before* and *after* values when used with `update`.